# Advice about building circular cabinet

Tags: design

I'm planning on building a circular cabinet where each shelf would have a different radius. All the shelves would be centered using a central pole running through their center. The cabinet will be surrounded by a frame to place the outer layer on it but it's not going to be that strong.

I'm wondering about how to support all of the shelves, what I thought of doing was placing spaced narrow boards (5cm width) in a semi circle layout or about ~210° (so as to not block the cabinet doors) between each pair of shelves. Each shelf (made of pine) would have to support about 15kg of weight. How many boards do you think would be enough? For example, if a 25cm radius shelf would have 13 boards (5cm width) spaced 8cm apart supporting it, would that be too many or too few?

The shelf would like this from above - the rectangles are the support boards and the bottom part is where the cabinet doors would go:

[image: shelf layout]

The basic layout of the cabinet is this (sorry for the crudeness of the sketch):
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It might be just my limitations, but I'm having a hard time visualizing your objective. Can you add a sketch with a bit of 3D aspect to it?

Comment: I added the basic cabinet layout @fred_dot_u

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Each shelf won't require many boards to support it from below (fewer than you're thinking) and even less if there is some support provided in the centre, like a collar of some sort on the central dowel. But put this aside for the moment, what's the surface or skin of this intended to be made from?? As drawn it appears it needs to conform to a compound curve, which isn't easy even in metal and impossible with many wood-based materials. Is there a particular reason you can't just make this a cylinder?

Comment: I'm not sure how to add support from the central dowel, I didn't find any curved shelf brackets so I was thinking something very simple like https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-4-in-Nickel-Plated-Angled-Shelf-Support-8-Pack-802884/206942358, therefore I don't think it'll provide that much support. If there's no support from the central dowel, how many do you think I would need @Graphus?

Comment: The surface is going to be made up of horizontal strips of flexible plywood that would encircle the support frame and would be laid one on top of the other, then I will sand them all smooth. This is a specific design I wanted to do, which is why I didn't make it a cylinder.

Comment: Why not use closet rod end flange supports secured to the central rod at the appropriate heights.  The shelf radii appear to be small enough that the central support from the brackets should be enough.  I would suggest that you also post another question to get reviews of your construction for the outside cabinet when you have worked out that design.

Comment: *"I'm not sure how to add support from the central dowel"* You could simply make a collar of some kind (from wood) that would slip down the dowel and he held at the required heigh with a machine screw/small bolt (acting like a grub screw if you know what one of those is). *"If there's no support from the central dowel, how many do you think I would need"* Perhaps only four would do it since the weight is very much transferred down through the structure vertically. But, IMO it would look better with more of them so maybe 6-8? BTW were you planning on glueing the boards or using nails or screws?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Ashlar, that's actually perfect, I didn't think those flanges could be used vertically but after searching around online it looks like people have done similar things.

Comment: Thanks @Graphus, I'm going to use the metal flange idea that Ashlar suggested as it would probably be stronger and easier than making it out of wood. About the support, that's great, I was hoping that since the weight is mostly transferred vertically, it would probably not require that many boards. You're right about the aesthetics, it would look better with like 6-8 so I'll do what you suggested. I'm planning on using screws since they would be much stronger, I thought of using small wooden dowels but I'm worried it'll eventually cause cracks in the boards if I drill the holes too off center.

Comment: I presume that some of the "crudeness" of the sketch includes the fact that the 3rd shelf up appears to be mounted off center. If you intend to have it rotate around the pole you've drawn, then the hole will actually need to be in the middle and this shelf will have to extend the same distance out on both the left and right (from the perspective of this drawing).

Comment: Yes @FreeMan, it's not really mounted off center, I just drew it badly :)

Comment: Since Graphus and Ashlar basically answered my question, should I add an answer to the question with what they said?

Comment: You should ask them to make an answer out of it, then accept it.

Comment: @Graphus and Ashlar, do you want to post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It is legal for you to answer our own question and as a newbie on the site, you could use the credits for privileges more than Graphus or I :)

Comment: Not only legal, but expected and perfectly acceptable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments by Graphus and Ashlar, it seems that I indeed overestimated the amount of support boards I would need. Since the weight is transferred mostly vertically, only 4 support boards would really be needed and any more will add support but will serve a mostly aesthetic reason. So for the example case I provided of a 25cm radius shelf, 8 would be a good number of support boards I think.

Also, I didn't find in my initial research curved shelf brackets that could be attached to the central dowel / pole but I hadn't thought of using metal closet rod end flanges for this purpose. They would be attached like in this example https://www.simplifiedbuilding.com/projects/diy-floating-shelves (in this case the pole is metal but the principal is the same). In this way, the shelf would be supported by the pole but I believe the support boards are still needed.